# Icons and top panel (anything except blank screen with background) don't show in fresh install of Ubuntu desktop in Vmware

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, kubuntu, vmware, iso

After a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop version 14.04 in VMware installed in my base Windows 10 OS, I got the following two problems when I powered on the virtual machine:

1. I get a blank screen with a background (I mean it is Not BLACK blank screen but the normal purple background) with no side bar of icons, no top panel, or any other controls. Screenshot given below.
2. I get a Missing Language Pack error. The only language I need is English. So can I ignore this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not that experienced in VMWare but if possible can you check whether Ctrl+Alt+T brings up the terminal or not.... I can't say this will help.. But if this works then there is some other problem, maybe in your installation.

Don't worry about it. I hope this is a minor problem....

Please check this. I hope some experienced user in VMWare will reply to your problem...